# Selenium .text doesn't get text that i want

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here the HTML Code:

```
<h4 class="page-header">
  " (111) Senior "
  <small>
    <font class="small"> 
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road">
        ::before
      </i>
      " Street 8.9 "
      <a href="htttp://" target="_blank">(master refrence)</a>
    </font>
  </small>
</h4>
```

My Python Code:

```
print("new adress: " + driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "small").text)
```

My Result:

```
new address: (Verification data, according to school updates)
```

I want result like this:

```
new address:  Street 8.9
```

Anyone have suggesion of my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use `find_element_by_css_selector` function.

```
print("new adress: " + driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h4.page-header font.small").text)
```

Comment: I still can't understand how to fill value function `find_element_by_css_selector` cause i use your suggestion but i get exception `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"h4.page-header font.small"}  `

Comment: `print("alamat terbaru: "+ driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"font.small").text)` i use that but i still get the same result `new address: (Verification data, according to school updates)`

Comment: First you need to search for `h4.page-header font.small` in the browser console.

Comment: Did you find out the tag ?

Comment: I already found the main problem of my code. the error can be happen cause I am forgot to move the link to the new one cause of that i can't get value that i want. that's why i got `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:`